# How to generalize the round methods

Tags: scala

I have the following four methods, using BigDecimal to round a number:

```
private def round(input: Byte, scale: Int): Byte = {
  BigDecimal(input).setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).byteValue()
}

private def round(input: Short, scale: Int): Short = {
  BigDecimal(input).setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).shortValue()
}

private def round(input: Int, scale: Int): Int = {
  BigDecimal(input).setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).intValue()
}

private def round(input: Long, scale: Int): Long = {
  BigDecimal(input).setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).longValue()
}
```

And plan to generalize it into a single round:

```
private def round[T](input: Any, scale: Int, f: (BigDecimal) => T): T = {
  f(BigDecimal(input.asInstanceOf[T]).setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
}
```

and use this round like this:

```
round[Byte](b, scale, _.byteValue)
round[Short](s, scale, _.shortValue)
```

But the above generalized `round` didn't work because `BigDecimal.apply` cannot apply to `T`, what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`Numeric`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.math.Numeric) type class

```
def round[T](input: T, scale: Int, f: BigDecimal => T)(implicit n: Numeric[T]): T = { 
   f(BigDecimal(n.toDouble(input)).setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)) 
}
```

Which can be used as:

```
round(5.525, 2, _.doubleValue)
res0: Double = 5.53

round(123456789L, -5, _.longValue)
res1: Long = 123500000
```

Another way might be to create a `BigDecimalConverter` type class, which is not as concise but solves the **issue of converting to `Double`** (which is not a good idea for a generic function, like Régis Jean-Gilles commented below).

Updated with a `fromBigDecimal` method to clean up the `round` function (thanks to Régis Jean-Gilles).

```
trait BigDecimalConverter[T] {
  def toBigDecimal(in: T) : BigDecimal
  def fromBigDecimal(bd: BigDecimal) : T
}

object BigDecimalConverter {
  implicit object IntToBigDecimal extends BigDecimalConverter[Int] {
    def toBigDecimal(in: Int) = BigDecimal(in)
    def fromBigDecimal(bd: BigDecimal) = bd.toInt
  }

  implicit object DoubleToBigDecimal extends BigDecimalConverter[Double] {
    def toBigDecimal(in: Double) = BigDecimal(in)
    def fromBigDecimal(bd: BigDecimal) = bd.toDouble
  }

  implicit object LongToBigDecimal extends BigDecimalConverter[Long] {
    def toBigDecimal(in: Long) = BigDecimal(in)
    def fromBigDecimal(bd: BigDecimal) = bd.toLong
  }

  implicit object BigDecimalToBigDecimal extends BigDecimalConverter[BigDecimal] {
    def toBigDecimal(in: BigDecimal) = in
    def fromBigDecimal(bd: BigDecimal) = bd
  }
}

def round[T](input: T, scale: Int)(implicit bdc: BigDecimalConverter[T]): T = 
   bdc.fromBigDecimal(
     bdc.toBigDecimal(input).setScale(scale, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
   )
```

Which can be correctly used with `Double`, `Long`, `BigDecimal`, ... :

```
round(10, 1)
round(Long.MaxValue - 1000L, -1)
round(BigDecimal("1234"), -2)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, why I should convert n to Double? will not Long type overflow?

Comment: @YijieShen n is not converted to a `Double`, n is an instance of the `Numeric` type class for the type `T` which converts `input` to a `Double`. The `Double` is then used to create a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: The conversion to double is a legitimate concern though. What if `input` itself is a `BigDecimal` (or anything that cannot safely be converted to `Double`)? Now it's true that OP's code snippet does not have this case, but even for a `Long` -- as in the 4th overload in OP's code -- it is unsafe (not all `Long`s fit into a double).

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles You are correct. I have updated my answer to handle `Long`, but it still doesn't work for other types with a `Numeric` type class (like `BigDecimal`).

Comment: Your update with the `ToBigDecimal` is probably what I would have done. Although it can easily seem pointless given that the whole code is bigger than the original code, the advantage is that the `ToBigDecimal` type class is a generic glue that can then be reused at will in other contexts. While you're at it, you could even add a `fromBigDecimal` method, allowing to entirely remove the need for the explicit `f` parameter (you would then just do `round(10, 1)` instead of `round(10, 1, _.toInt)`)

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles That is a nice improvement, which cleans up the `round` function very nicely. I have updated my answer.

Comment: PeterNeyens, RégisJean-Gilles, Thanks for the informative discussion and nice answer.